When I install Access Runtime 2019, Programs and Features show I installed Access Runtime 2016. Is this only 2016 in name only?
I downloaded and installed the executable for MS Access Runtime components from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/download-and-install-microsoft-365-access-runtime-185c5a32-8ba9-491e-ac76-91cbe3ea09c9?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us

When I completed I checked Apps & Features, it shows Microsoft Access Runtime 2016 - en-us.  Is this correct or is this a bug?

Did I just install Microsoft Access Runtime 2019 components or not?

I do believe you are correct. Since office 2016, there not really a "version" anymore in as much as they now simply update office all the time, and the concept of some big next new release does not really exist anymore. In other words, office is often updated, changed and enhanced, and the idea of some big next release is quite much a thing of the past. So, office is updated all the time now - not really much of a concept of some "version" anymore, and this concept is fast going away due to continues updates and adding of features.

I was able to get this answered on a Microsoft blog: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/when-i-install-access-runtime-2019-programs-and/9bae4a96-d7f4-48cb-b708-d9df81ba6e06?page=2&messageId=dc102a20-7b70-4a00-9f79-2a5b58f67b9d

Very well, so they DO plan to update the version number, and for the time being they just not done so.

Yes.  Simple change, but so difficult to get done.  Remember TESTING is your friend.
